# Idiomatic way to accept unordered function parameters

Tags: function, go

I'm learning Go.

In JavaScript, it is trivial to define a function that accepts multiple unordered parameters by encapsulating the parameters in an object:

```
// define our function
var foo = function(params) {
  // ... don't care
};

// specify parameters as an object literal
var params = {
  alpha:   true,
  bravo:   10,
  charlie: "delta",
};

// pass the params to the function
foo(options);
```

What is the idiomatic way to accomplish this in Go? I'm aware that Go has hashes, structs, types, and interfaces, but I'm not sure which is best used here.

Note that I'd like to export the function in question for use outside of its own package.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this (the most direct equivalent would be params map[string]interface{} ), but you are then subverting the typing system and writing javascript in go. This makes things easier to write the first time, and exponentially harder to read, use and debug later. Try to avoid doing this, except where the data is stringly typed anyway (e.g. request params).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way. Encapsulate them in a struct.

```
type FooParameters struct {
    Alpha   bool
    Bravo   int
    Charlie string
}

func Foo(params FooParameters) {
    fmt.Print(params.Charlie)
    // ... don't care
}

func main() {
    // Any order is fine
    params := FooParameters{
        Bravo:   10,
        Charlie: "delta",
        Alpha:   true,
    }
    Foo(params)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/cU0Jd7_jN8

---

You asked about anonymous structs, and they're idiomatic (they show up in stdlib from time to time), but they're a bit of a pain to use, so you usually don't want them unless the struct is very small and used very rarely. For example, this is what your interface would look like with an anonymous struct.

```
func Foo(params struct {
    Alpha   bool
    Bravo   int
    Charlie string
}) {
    fmt.Print(params.Charlie)
    // ... don't care
}

func main() {
    // Any order is fine
    params := struct {
        Alpha   bool
        Bravo   int
        Charlie string
    }{
        Bravo:   10,
        Charlie: "delta",
        Alpha:   true,
    }
    Foo(params)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/r4yXh7oADe

It's pretty hard to read IMO, and a lot to type. Naming the type is just a convenience. Anywhere you use a named type, you could use an anonymous type (but as Milo notes, you generally shouldn't).

Comment: So is it essentially "un-idiomatic" in Go to use an anonymous struct in this case? Is the convention to define a `struct` type (`FooParameters`)? Coming from other languages, this seems over-engineered, but perhaps this is simply how things are done in Go :)

Comment: @ChrisAllenLane this is how things are done in go. If you used an anonymous struct, how would you tell `Foo` what kind of parameter to expect?

Comment: @AdamSmith, I'm not sure. "This is how things are done in go" is essentially just the confirmation that I needed to hear. I was merely wary of "unknown unknowns" that I had not considered. Thanks for the input.

Comment: It should be noted that anonymous structs are very rare. Just use a named type.

Comment: JS has very weak types. Makes it easy to write, but harder to change in a large project. If you changed Bravo from int to string, then it'd be very hard in a massive JS project to be sure you fixed every use. It's also very hard to know every parameter that Foo() accepts; you have to hope the docs are right or read the impl. Go has strong types, which requires more up-front work, but when you change things the compiler tells you every place that needs to be fixed & the signature tells you all the parameters. It's a trade-off. Personally I prefer strong types, but it's a trade-off.

Comment: @RobNapier On the topic of strong versus weak typing, I used to *loathe* type systems of all types. Coming from hacking away in Python, I felt that I knew that Real Programming could be done without the coder having to worry about silly things like strict types. A decade later I'm mostly working in Go and learning Haskell, and frankly type systems are a godsend, *especially* now in Haskell whose type system is so strong that their documentation reference accepts queries like `String -> [String]` or `String -> Bool` or even `[a] -> a` for generics.

Comment: e.g. I recently needed to look up the Haskell function to list a directory's contents. I knew the type signature would take a string for the path and return a list of strings for the contents. This translates in Haskell to `String -> IO [String]`. Searching that immediately returns `getDirectoryContents` which has type `FilePath -> IO [FilePath]`, because `FilePath` is a type alias for `String`. Magic!

Comment: Yep; of course you wind up really *needing* Hoogle to find anything… I often miss code completion when working in Haskell. Moving from languages like Swift, Go, and Haskell to Python, the sheer sloppiness of it drove me crazy. I find it impossible to figure out what many Python functions return, and you just have to experiment in the repl and hope that it never changes because you never know what's promised and what just happens to work. But, after working in Python for a while, I've grown to like it and I've done excellent work there. So it's a big world :D

Answer (score 1):

You may use this construction. This way `a` inside function became a slice - thats why I return first element as `a[0]`. 
Limitation - only last parameter can be variadic.

```
func f(a... int) int {
    return a[0]
}
```

How to accept:

**Any number of any parameters in strict order**: you can pass a very abstract type - empty `interface{}` and then call

```
func f(a... interface{}) interface{} {
    return a[0]
}
f("aaa", 2, []int{3,4})
```

But do not use it tooo much :) - you lose all the benefits of static typisation.

**Fixed types and number of parameters**:  use struct.

**Any number of any parameters unordered**:  pass it as `map[interface{}]interface{}`:

```
func b(m map[interface{}]interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/0MeMm9x0JT

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, in your example, wouldn't a variadic work only if all of the parameters were of type int? What if I need to mix types?

Comment: There's one hack  - you may pass all abstract `interface{}`

Comment: Even using the `interface` trick, though, wouldn't the function implementation be dependent on the order in which parameters were passed? Is there an idiomatic way to pass unordered (named?) parameters?

Comment: Yes, interface helps to accept any number of any parameters, but their order matter. If you want them without order but with names you may use `map[interface{}]interface{}`. It's analog of JS object in term of string keys `{}`.

Comment: Note that using `interface{}` this way is almost always very bad Go. `map[interface{}]interface{}` in particular is a type to be strongly avoided unless it's absolutely necessary. Eugene is correct that this is possible; it's just not the normal way to write it.